# delimit the output of xml extract function in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

I am in a bit of a pickle, I have an Oracle DB table with a blob column that holds XML data.
I have managed to convert the blob to a suitable XML type and extracted the tag I need.
But here is the problem. My XML has multiple tags of the same name ("`//source-column/name/text()`") and I need to extract all of them in a comma-separated form (preferably in the same row)

my XML looks something like this:

```
<column>   <source-column index="1">
    <schema>ABC</schema>
    <table>sales</table>
    <name>column_alpha</name>   </source-column>   <source-column index="2">
    <schema>ABC</schema>
    <table>sales</table>
    <name>column_beta</name>   </source-column>   <source-column index="3">
    <schema>ABC</schema>
    <table>sales</table>
    <name>column_gamma</name>   </source-column> </column>
```

the output I am looking to get is something like this:

```
"column_alpha, column_beta, column_gamma"
```

the output i am getting right now is:

```
"column_alphacolumn_betacolumn_gamma"
```

I also have a size issue as the blob exceeds the 4000 size limit in some cases and the buffer throws an error so I have had to convert the blob to a clob and then to varchar2 to be able to get any data out.
The query i am currently using is:

```
select 
  xmltype(xmltype(data_column, nls_charset_id('CHAR_CS')).getclobval()).extract('//column/source-column/name/text()').getstringval() as "column_values"
from blob_table;
```

I have tried listagg, xmlagg, and xmlelement but to no avail. Please Help

Comment: i can also work with a solution with a varray that stores all the output from extract